# Which status code should I return?

Tags: http-status-codes, custom-errors, server-error, dropbox-sdk-js

I am doing an dropbox.js upload. I am checking for errors on the server and returning them to my frontend via json. So far so good.

```
 header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
            header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
            die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 100)));
```

on my frontend I can catch the error and do some nice stuff to alert the user

```
error: function(file, errorMessage,  xhr) {
     console.log(xhr);
     // catch the error and alert the user
  }
```

The problem is the errors are not really 'server errors' so how should I return them in the header? A 500 does not seem appropriate. It does not I suppose really matter but would nice to return the right type of error.

The kind of errors include

- filename is not unique
- wrong file type
- file is too large

What is the best status code to use?

Thanks.

Comment: All of these errors come under Bad Request. and http code for bad request is 400.

Comment: Yes was thinking that could use a generic 400 for them all, although I like - 418 I'm a teapot

Comment: but "bad request" means a request malformed or invalid from client-side was detected (*due to an apparent client error*), not a server exception. consider "409 Conflict" or "418 I'm a teapot", or "422 Unprocessable Entity" or keep 500 and encode the application-specific error in the message text.